# How to create 360 degree turnable holographic video from sequence of point clouds

Tags: animation, blender-internal-render-engine, video

I have a sequence of point clouds in .ply format. Now, I want to convert them into a 360 degree turnable (free view point) video where each frame of video contains data from single ply file. Is there any way to do it?

Thanks,
Nikhil

Comment: By "free view point" do you mean that you can change your point of view interactively? That would be a functionality of the video viewer (comparable to a panorama viewer, although different functionality). You can render a turntable videos in Blender by either animating the camera around the object or by animating the object to rotate around its Z-axis with the camera at a fixed position.

Comment: @rjg I want to get an output something similar to this [link](https://youtu.be/SkJG-uFU2yA?t=19). Here each frame of the video is a separate .obj file, due to this fact I think animating camera won't work. Please share any inputs you have, it would be really helpful.

Comment: I see, this has nothing to do with Blender. What you're trying to accomplish is also known as temporal consistency / 4D reconstruction. This means you're trying to create a sequence of meshes that remain relatively unchanged in their topology while also approximating the motion as accurately as possible.

Comment: I could give you links to research papers, but I'm not aware that a (free) general purpose software for this task exists.